# Cannot pass server object from one jade file to another jade file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

I have just started using jade and node. I am passing an object from node to jade template (`parent.jade`) and including the same jade file (`parent.jade`) to another file (`child.jade`). it is depicted as follows:

Node part:

```
res.render('parent.jade', {data: mydata});
```

Then in `parent.jade` I am receiving the data correctly:

```
doctype html
html
    head

        title parent
        script(type="text/javascript" src="/resources/file_javascript.js").
            var data_from_node = !{JSON.stringify(data)}; //getting the data in javascript file 

    body(data-title="parent")

        div#header(class="wrap")
            include header.pug

        ul#list(class="nav nav-tabs")

        footer(id="footer" class="footer")
            include footer.pug
```

In `child.pug` I am including the parent file but could not get the data object. I have tried everything but nothing is working here I am including it in the following way:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title child.pug

    body(data-title="child")
        div(class="wrap")
            include parent.pug //here I am including parent.pug getting the content right
        div#mydiv(class="tab-content")
            include table.pug
        footer(id="footer" class="footer")
            include footer.pug

        script(type='text/javascript').
            var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)}; //getting null here
        script(type = "text/javascript", src = "/resources/file_javascript.js")
```

Is there any way to get the "data object" in `child.pug` from `parent.pug` because I am getting null in `child.pug`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. When you call `res.render` in Node.js, the context variables you pass to that template are only remembered while that template is being rendered. If you want to let `child.pug` have access to that variable, you must actively pass it to that template, as well (when you call `res.render("child.pug", {...})`).